# How to efficiently run through rows of data to match a criterion using excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Normally what I do on my program is using logic like:

```
Total_rows_worksheet = Worksheets("Sample").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 to Total_rows_worksheet
    If Worksheets("Sample").Cells(i,1)=Criteria Then
       [Perform this action]
    End If
Next i
```

However, when the number of rows get large, code that runs through the entire sheet gets a bit slow. Also, I remember my programmer friend telling me that it is a common mistake for beginner programmers to run through all the data. The correct way according to him was to point to the rows of interest, but I do not know exactly how to do that in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Disable screen updating and calculation before the loop and it will increase the speed immensely.

```
Sub testing()
    'Disable screen updating and calculation
    Dim uRange As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Total_rows_worksheet = Worksheets("Sample").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To Total_rows_worksheet
        If Worksheets("Sample").Cells(i, 1) = "OK" Then
            If uRange Is Nothing Then
                Set uRange = Worksheets("Sample").Cells(i, 1)
            Else
                Set uRange = Union(uRange, Worksheets("Sample").Cells(i, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    uRange.Value = "THIS USED TO SAY OK"
    'Enable screen updating and calculation when done
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Edit 1: Depending on the task, another way to speed things up is to change all at once by adding ranges to a Union.

Note: Screen updating should be the first to be disabled and the last to be enabled when going for speed in Excel-VBA. There are other things that can be disable like Events that also help if you have event specific triggers.

Comment: That's true also disabling automatic calculations then re-enabling them can give a significant boost to speed or storing data into arrays before transferring to the worksheet as well. Although when it comes to the loop logic I wonder if there's a faster way that requires less computational effort.

Comment: Yes and no, the loop needs to remain the same, loop all items because you don't know all the time which rows has the data and which is the last row with data. However, instead of processing the action on every cell that is found, you can add the cell to a Union and change the whole Union at once after the loop, of course sometimes other factors may not allow you to change all of it at once. Please see the edit i have made to show an example of a Union and changing all cells at once.

Answer (score 0):

You might use something similar as:

```
    Public roww
Sub Main()
    Dim sht
    roww = InputBox("Start Row", "Row to start", "", 8000, 6000)
    If roww <> "" Then
        Set sht = Sheets("Your sheet")
        'this is a validation
        Do Until sht.Cells(roww, "A").Value = ""
        'this is other optional validation
            If sht.Cells(roww, "Y").Text <> "" Then
                [Perform this action]
                roww = roww + 1
            Else
                roww = roww + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Else
End If
MsgBox ("The Process has been completed")
End Sub
```

It should stop until the the last row with data.